# bootstrap modals only firing once with remote datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with a list of items and each item has a `<select>` with a list of statuses. Here's the process.

- When the status is changed, it should fire a modal.
- The modal is pulling in ajax data and works fine.
- The user can then click continue or cancel out of the modal box.

This works the first time, but as soon as the modal is dismissed, the modal won't load a second time. The data is updating - I can see it in the inspect element, but the modal itself isn't firing more than once.

Here's the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<select class="status form-control" data-id="14" data-ref="PT6F7SW514" name="status">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Pending</option>
    <option value="1">Approved</option>
    <option value="2">Rejected</option>
</select>
...
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Goes Here</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.status').change(function(){
        var status = $(this);
        var val = $(status).val();
        var id = $(status).attr('data-id');
        var ref = $(status).attr('data-ref');

        $('.modal-body').load('/ajax/status/' + ref + '/' + val);
        $('#modal').modal();

    });
});
```

Again, this is a table with multiple items, each of which has a `.status` select field. I can see in the console on the second attempt to fire the modal I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Associated to this line in the JS:

```
$('#modal').modal();
```

If I comment out `$('.modal-body').load()`, it works.

I tried rewriting it into a separate ajax call instead of using `.load()`, but I have the same problem there. It seems like as soon as I manipulate the '.modal-body' it looses the ability to fire the modal.

Comment: `.load()` is async. You need to move the `.modal()` into a callback.

Comment: @cvrebert - I'm being a bit thick: can you show an example of what you mean by in a callback?

Comment: `load` has a `complete` argument that's a callback function. Supply a function for that argument, and do the `modal()` call in that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. it wasn't actually a problem with the modal. The view I was firing (using Laravel) also included `<head>` and `<body>` tags (the modal is meant for an email preview). This was breaking the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('#modal').modal('show'); // or .modal('hide')
```

to show or hide a modal